# Problems with creating slug

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application that handles two roles of administrator and developer. The administrator data as developer is created without problems but when trying to use slug the program does not recognize them.

This is my model:

```
class ProfileAdministrator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Administrator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='profiles/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


class ProfileDeveloper(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='profiles/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug


@receiver(post_save, sender=Administrator)
def set_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        ProfileAdministrator.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Developer)
def set_profile_developer(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        ProfileDeveloper.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProfileAdministrator)
def set_slug_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.user:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.user)


@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProfileDeveloper)
def set_slug_profile_administrator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.user:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.user)
```

The program works fine even when I enter the slug, it does not recognize them, but the data is created correctly.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not recognize them"?

Comment: Well, the slug is not created and I don't know why, the data without the slug does it without problems

Comment: Is the slug empty when the model is saved or are you getting an error?

Comment: It is empty, no error appears

Comment: Are you sure the signals are being run? Can you add logging or use a debugger to see if the signals are triggered?

Comment: I already used the debugger, now with more precision I was making a mistake and it was that I was calling the signals in the same way, uf thanks for recommending the debugger, I'm just learning thank you very much.